# Most Pythonic way to handle exception caused by functools.reduce when the iterable yields no elements?

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming, reduce

Python's `functools.reduce` throws an exception when the iterable passed to it yields no elements.

Here's how I currently use it:

```
some_list = []  # empty list should be permissible

functools.reduce(
    lambda left, right: pandas.merge(left, right, on=['idx'], how='outer'),
    some_list
)
```

This throws an exception if the list contains no elements.

What I actually want it to do is return `None` if the list is empty. But that can't be achieved by setting the initial value to `None` because `None` cannot be merged with a `DataFrame` type in the call to `pandas.merge`.

I could wrap this statement in a function and perform a return-early check like so:

```
def f(some_list):

    if len(some_list) < 1:
        return None
```

But this doesn't seem like a great solution. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Why not just wrap it in a `Try` `Except <relevant functools exception>` block, and `return None` if the exception is hit?

Comment: Why _is_ None the appropriate value? The caller can't then rely on getting a dataframe back. Also checking the length limits this to sized collections, rather than iterables more generally.

Comment: Interesting question. Can you work with an empty DataFrame when the input is empty? If so the empty DataFrame can be your initial value. Failing that, I think explicitly checking for empty input and returning None in that case is the clearest way to implement it. My advice is to steer away from handling an exception, even if it is equivalent; I find that just a little harder to comprehend if I'm reading it. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an initial value as the 3rd argument to `reduce`. The initial value is used in two ways:

1. If the iterable is empty, `reduce` simply returns the initial value.
2. If the iterable is non-empty, `reduce` adds the initial value to the beginning of the iterable.

That is, with an initial value `x`, `reduce(f, iterable, x)` is effectively the same as `reduce(f, itertools.chain([x], iterable))`*.

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(add, [], "bar")
"bar"
>>> reduce(add, ["foo", "bar"])
"foobar"
>>> reduce(add, ["bar"], "foo")
"foobar"
```

In your case, you can provide an empty dataframe as the initial value. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial, reduce


l = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,2,3], ["foo", "bar", "baz"]), columns=["idx", "name"])
r = pd.DataFrame([4,5,6], columns=["idx"])

identity = pd.DataFrame(columns=["idx"])
merger = partial(pd.merge, on='idx', how='outer')
```

Then

```
>>> reduce(merger, [], identity)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [idx]
Index: []
>>> reduce(merger, [l], identity)
   idx name
0    1  foo
1    2  bar
2    3  baz
>>> reduce(merger, [l])
   idx name
0    1  foo
1    2  bar
2    3  baz
>>> reduce(merger, [r])
   idx
0    4
1    5
2    6
>>> reduce(merger, [r], identity)
   idx
0    4
1    5
2    6
>>> reduce(merger, [l, r], identity)
   idx name
0    1  foo
1    2  bar
2    3  baz
3    4  NaN
4    5  NaN
5    6  NaN
```

---

* `itertools.chain` is basically the iterator version of `+`. Chaining together two iterators produces an iterator that produces the values from the first iterator, followed by the values from the second.

Comment: This doesn't work for the reasons specified in the question

Comment: Is there a reason why your function needs to return `None` instead of an empty data frame?

Comment: Is signals to downstream code that no further processing should be done. Returning an empty dataframe doesn't do this because there is no easy way to check if a dataframe is empty. In addition: an empty dataframe might be empty for legitimate reasons and that doesn't mean the same thing as "don't do further processing".

Comment: In that case, I would just explicitly check the argument before using `reduce`. (Better yet, you should probably detect that the list is empty *before* calling `f`.)

Comment: Also, as stated in the question, this will not work. You cannot merge an empty dataframe with a non-empty dataframe.

Comment: There's empty, and there's *empty*. An initial value like `DataFrame(columns=['idx'])` (rather than `DataFrame()`) should work.

Comment: Your suggestion, if I understand correctly, is create a dataframe with a single column `idx` and then set that as the index column? Then merge?

Comment: Yes, but as I said earlier, I *would* treat an empty input list as a special case and return `None`, rather than treating it as a vacuous set of frames to merge.

Comment: Your suggestion I think is actually quite good. I re-worked the downstream code to be able to cope with empty dataframes (mostly just by changing the operations so they will work ok with this). I was doing some jank thing where I tried to re-create the same dataframe structure without any rows, but this was pretty bad because I was adding in some additional columns only to later remove them. It turns out those extra column names are not needed and it will work with just the index as you suggest. This is actually now not the same question but thanks for the suggestion. It is a good one.